# How to crop string from multiple txt files?

Tags: c#

I have thousands of .log files and I need to find some string in all of the files.

I will explain with example: on all of .log files I have string calles "AAA" and after that string I have anumber that can be diffrenet from one log file to other log file. I know how to search the AAA string. what I dont knew is how to crop only the string number that is after the AAA string.

**update:** 
the .log file containes a lot of lines.
on the .log file I have only 1 line that contains the string "A12A". 
after that line I have anumber (for examle: 5465). 
what I need is to extract the number after the A12A. 
note: there is a spacing between the A12A to the 5465 string number.

**example:** 
.log file : "assddsf dfdfsd dfd A12A 5465 dffdsfsdf dfdf dfdf "
 what I need to extract: 5465.

what I have so far is:

```
// Modify this path as necessary.
string startFolder = @"c:\program files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\";

// Take a snapshot of the file system.
System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(startFolder);

// This method assumes that the application has discovery permissions
// for all folders under the specified path.
IEnumerable<System.IO.FileInfo> fileList = dir.GetFiles("*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);

string searchTerm = @"Visual Studio";

// Search the contents of each file.
// A regular expression created with the RegEx class
// could be used instead of the Contains method.
// queryMatchingFiles is an IEnumerable<string>.
var queryMatchingFiles =
    from file in fileList
    where file.Extension == ".htm"
    let fileText = GetFileText(file.FullName)
    where fileText.Contains(searchTerm)
    select file.FullName;

// Execute the query.
Console.WriteLine("The term \"{0}\" was found in:", searchTerm);
foreach (string filename in queryMatchingFiles)
{
    Console.WriteLine(filename);
}

// Keep the console window open in debug mode.
Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
Console.ReadKey();
}

// Read the contents of the file.
static string GetFileText(string name)
{
    string fileContents = String.Empty;

// If the file has been deleted since we took 
// the snapshot, ignore it and return the empty string.
if (System.IO.File.Exists(name))
{
    fileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(name);
}
return fileContents;
```

}

Comment: What separates each line? the \r or \n? Or a '<p>' or '<br />' tag? Either way, you could simply split by the thing which creates the new line and then search your array for your string. Then you'll know what ever index has the search string, yours is the next. Of course, if you have '<br /><br />' (2 line breaks in a row) this logic breaks!

Comment: Could you update your question and give an example about the content, what part within that you are searching for and what should be extracted? To give a good answer, it really depends on these things (e.g. makes a RegEx sense, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend the following code for doing the search itself:

```
private static readonly string _SearchPattern = "A12A";
private static readonly Regex _NumberExtractor = new Regex(@"\d+");

private static IEnumerable<Tuple<String, int>> FindMatches()
{
    var startFolder = @"D:\";
    var filePattern = @"*.htm";
    var matchingFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(startFolder, filePattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    foreach (var file in matchingFiles)
    {
        // What encoding do your files use?
        var lines = File.ReadLines(file, Encoding.UTF8);

        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            int number;

            if (TryGetNumber(line, out number))
            {
                yield return Tuple.Create(file, number);

                // Stop searching that file and continue with the next one.
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

private static bool TryGetNumber(string line, out int number)
{
    number = 0;

    // Should casing be ignored??
    var index = line.IndexOf(_SearchPattern, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

    if (index >= 0)
    {
        var numberRaw = line.Substring(index + _SearchPattern.Length);
        var match = _NumberExtractor.Match(numberRaw);
        return Int32.TryParse(match.Value, out number);
    }

    return false;
}
```

The reasons are that when doing I/O operations, the drive itself is normally the bottleneck. So it doesn't make sense to do anything in parallel or to read a lot of data from the file into memory without using it.

By using the [`Directory.EnumerateFiles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571.aspx) method the drive will be searched lazily and you can start examining the first file, right after it was found. The same holds true for the [`File.ReadLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383357.aspx) method. It lazily iterates through the file while you are searching for your pattern.

Through this approach you should get a maximum speed (depending on your hard-drive performance) cause it makes the minimum needed I/O calls needed to get the files and content to your code.

Comment: thanks. will line.Startswith("AAA") search entire line for AAA?

Comment: No, it only checks if the line begins with "AAA" (hence the name). Take a look at [`String.StartsWith`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131452.aspx)

Comment: thanks. but the AAA is somewhere in the middle of the line

Comment: Could you update your question and give an example about the content, what part within that you are searching for and what should be extracted? To give a good answer, it really depends on these things (e.g. makes a RegEx sense, etc.)